# geom_rect alternating colour on discrete scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a faceted forest plot using `ggplot2`. The y-scale uses discrete factors. For the panel background I would like to have alternating rectangles (grey, white), that span 50% either side of the axis ticks and panel grid lines on the y axis, to improve the background contrast between adjacent factor points. From some other questions on SO I believe `geom_rect` is what I should be using but I cannot figure out how to have alternating rectangles using the discrete factor scale. Thanks in advance.

Example plot:

```
require(tidyverse)

##data frame
df1 <- tibble('outcome.var' = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 
'J'),
          'coefficient' = c(-0.08, -0.01, -0.06, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, -0.08, -0.1, 0.1, 0.2),
          'conf.low' = c(-0.12, -0.03, -0.09, 0.01, 0.02,  0.01, -0.10, -0.2, 0.05, 0.1),
          'conf.high' = c(-0.05, 0.02, -0.03, 0.03, -0.01, 0.04, -0.06, 0, 0.2, 0.3),
          'p.value' =c(0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.10, 0.02, 0.13, 0.11, 0.01, 0.01, 0.04)) %>%
  mutate(significant = ifelse(p.value > 0.05, 'P > 0.05', 'P < 0.05'),
     label = case_when(
       .$outcome.var %in% c('A', 'B', 'C') ~ '1',
       .$outcome.var %in% c('D', 'E', 'F') ~ '2',
       .$outcome.var %in% c('G', 'H') ~ '3',
       .$outcome.var %in% c('I', 'J') ~ '4'))


p1 <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(outcome.var, coefficient)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), shape = 32) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = significant), fill = 'white') +
  geom_hline(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, yintercept = 0, colour = "grey40", 
      size = 0.5, linetype = "solid") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey95")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(19, 21)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('black', 'black')) + 
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(label ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "x") +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(face = 'bold'))
```

Comment: You mean `background < 0` one color & `background > 0` another color?

Comment: @PoGibas Background colour alternating. C, A, E, H, J should be grey, and the other factors white. I would like the coloured rectangles to span half the distance either side of the y-axis factor grid lines, for example the rectangle for E, should span from halfway between E and F, to halfway between E and D